# how to know the directory where there are the GraphDB executables

Tags: ubuntu, directory, path, executable, graphdb

I have installed GraphDB on Ubunto 20.4.
How can I get the directory where there are the GraphDB executables.

```
which graphDB
```

The command above does not return any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphDB directory is located in /opt/graphdb-free
The data directory (repositories, logs, configurations) is in /home/user/.graphdb